# Bot Framework Formflow EnumSelectOne template doesn't work on telegram

Tags: botframework, telegram-bot

I'm facing a problem using FormFlow feature.

My model has the propertie below:

```
[Describe("Site")] 
[Template(TemplateUsage.EnumSelectOne, "Em qual {&} será feita a reserva? {||}", ChoiceStyle = ChoiceStyleOptions.Default]
[Template(TemplateUsage.NotUnderstood, "Não entendi sua resposta... você precisa me informar o nome de um site válido ou ainda pode clicar num dos botões acima")]
public Site? Site { get; set; }
```

Site is a enum, and it renders a list of buttons. It works properly on webchat but not in Telegram.

When the user select an option in webchat, the answer is prompted below and the bot continue the dialog. However, in telegram, the user select an option and the answer is not prompted on the chat and the framework stay waiting a user interaction.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Tks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of code?

Comment: You can see the whole project here: https://github.com/rcarubbi/Atento.ReservaVagaPOC

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question... To work properly on telegram you need to put `ChoiceStyle = ChoiceStyleOptions.Auto` on Template attribute.

Here the whole property configuration:

```
[Describe("Tipo de solicitante")]
 [Template(TemplateUsage.EnumSelectOne, "Que {&} você é? {||}", ChoiceStyle = ChoiceStyleOptions.Auto)]
 [Template(TemplateUsage.NotUnderstood, "Não entendi sua resposta... você precisa me informar se é funcionário ou terceiro ou ainda pode clicar num dos botões acima")]
 public TipoSolicitante? TipoSolicitante { get; set; }
```